# substract the week day from a date in Hive SQL

Tags: date, hive, hiveql, weekday

I'm completely new to Hive SQL and I need to do the following.
I have a column which includes a date and what I would like to do is to create a new one which will be the Sunday before this date.
In xls I would write the following:
my_date-WEEKDAY(my_date,1)+1
and in sql:

```
DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, my_date)-1), my_date)
```

I tried the following in Hive SQL:

```
DATE_SUB (my_date, date_format(my_date,'u')-1)
```

but date_format returns a string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the result of `date_format` to `int` and do the arithmetic.

```
DATE_SUB(my_date,cast(date_format(my_date,'u') as int)%7)
```